# how to reset the form element inside ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs

I am still a beginer in angularjs

How to reset the input field in the below plunker.
Enter the value in the input field and click on review will populate the value in the view. I need to clear those on clicking reset

```html
<iframe src='http://embed.plnkr.co/JzmpYK/preview'></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `reset()` function so that it is equaling a copy of the original `vehicles` variable. You want to reference an object that is not being updated like a masterCopy variable.

```
$scope.vehiclesMaster = angular.copy($scope.vehicles);

$scope.reset = function(){
   $scope.vehicles = $scope.vehiclesMaster;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I implemented the same [http://plnkr.co/edit/8lF1Lv?p=preview] as u mentioned, but it is clearing only one time means if you entered the the value in the field and click on reset it is clearing, but if reenter the value and click on reset it is not clearing..can you please help me where i am missing